# checking variable using typeof and length

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm seeing people doing this

```
if(typeof myVar === 'string' && myVar.length > 0) {

}
```

why not just `if(myVar) {}` ??

I use typeof to debug, never use it in real life app.

Comment: What if the value of `myVar` is `18` or an object reference? That test ensures that the value is a non-empty string. Just testing to see whether it's truth-y could lead to an error.

Comment: Apparently because their `myVar` is not always a string. Which isn't the best practice of course, but what could we do?

Comment: Which people? Where do they do this? Have you asked them why? How would we know, we're not the authors of that code?

Comment: This question would better be answered in a specific context where you saw this structure being used where we could see the surrounding code and then answer why the author decided to use this.  Obviously, the generic answer is because the author wanted to make sure they were being passed a string that was not empty (not a number, not an array, not an object, not a boolean, etc...).  Why that check is there depends entirely upon the context of the code which you have not included.

Answer (score 0):

if(myVar) {}), doesn't check if the value of myVar is string or not

where as `typeof myVar === 'string'` helps you do that.

`myVar.length > 0` used to check that myVar has some characters but it's not foolproof as even empty spaces count as characters. For Example:

let x = '  ';

then x.length is 2

Hope this helps.

Comment: why important use "===" to compare typeof result with a constant?

Comment: you can also use == to compare it. As js is loosely typed, its better to use === rather than == everywhere, but == works at this spot of type of, As you are sure typeof returns a string.

Comment: better everywhere except this :) and what about the speed? I measured and get 40-50% speed up to non-typesafe equality.

Comment: ya, in terms of speed I would agree == is better and this place == would be rite.

Comment: okay, this is not important, because on my machine has 40-50% but I need use a cycle with 100million iteration to measure 0.1 sec different. nobody runs huge loops in a webpage. and this case the both side of relation is string. but I seeing that solution everywhere. why? nobody think about it as we? I don't understand the direction of javascript evolution :(

Comment: I think as the performance is variant on several things like the js engine, laptop and several other stuffs. Also as it is also better to code everything as === rather than == since humans making mistake is general and === can save lot of those error activities. Thats probably why people use it that way

Comment: I develop for web 10+ years but never found error because missing type check. why so important this in last few years? Can you show me some github issues which reason is a missing type check?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147558/discussion-between-neovire-and-sarkiroka).

Answer (score 0):

This is a polemics.

If you write your code, and you know "myVar is a string" then your statement is good enough

```
if(myVar){}
```

But if monkeys calls your code, or anybody who has not sense of the expected data types, you must check the type of variable, and other things. In this case you must use === instead of == because what happend when typeof function returns a non-string value?

Crazy world